# Unwanted space between page number and margin when using titletoc

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

When using the `titletoc` package, how does one get rid of the space between the page of the chapter, section, ecc and the right margin of the page?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
% ----------
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pc]%
{\addvspace{2.7ex}\large}%
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{0pc}\hspace{1pc}}
{}%
{\nolinebreak\enspace\textbullet\enspace\hfill\thecontentspage}
% ----------
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\chapter{Another chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\contentsmargin` sets the rightmargin in the table of contents:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% ----------
\contentsmargin{0pt}
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pc]%
{\addvspace{2.7ex}\large}%
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{0pc}\hspace{1pc}}
{}%
{\nolinebreak\enspace\textbullet\enspace\hfill\thecontentspage}
% ----------
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\chapter{Another chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]